# adding chatgpt's api to a discord command in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, openai-api, chatgpt-api

i have this code which is fine as far as i know but it keeps hitting me with error below, the api key is correct and the code is all good and the api is working so why am i getting this error.

Code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: "MY API KEY HERE",
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('chat')
    .setDescription('Get an AI-generated response based on your message')
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option.setName('message')
        .setDescription('The message to generate a response from')
        .setRequired(true)),
  async execute(interaction) {
    const message = interaction.options.getString('message');

    try {
      const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
        model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages: [{ role: "user", content: message }],
      });

      const response = completion.data.choices[0].text.trim();

      await interaction.reply(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      await interaction.reply({ content: 'Sorry, there was an error processing your request!', ephemeral: true });
    }
  },
};
```

The code checks out unless there is something i don't know that is wrong

Error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\rzn bot\node_modules\openai\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\rzn bot\node_modules\openai\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\rzn bot\node_modules\openai\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:322:11)        
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'User-Agent': 'OpenAI/NodeJS/3.2.1',
      Authorization: 'Bearer THE API KEY HERE',
      'Content-Length': 74
    },
    method: 'post',
    data: '{"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo","messages":[{"role":"user","content":"hey"}]}',
    url: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: true,
    _last: false,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: 74,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api.openai.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api.openai.com',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: null,
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: -1,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 5000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 12141,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 343,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 341
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 1,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'POST /v1/chat/completions HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: OpenAI/NodeJS/3.2.1\r\n' +
      'Authorization: Bearer THE API KEY HERE' +
      'Content-Length: 74\r\n' +
      'Host: api.openai.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype],
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: true,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/v1/chat/completions',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: null,
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 404,
      statusMessage: 'Not Found',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 14,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'api.openai.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 74,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      authorization: [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  response: {
    status: 404,
    statusText: 'Not Found',
    headers: {
      date: 'Thu, 02 Mar 2023 22:37:48 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'content-length': '158',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      vary: 'Origin',
      'x-request-id': '40456c1da0117d70199e713b83ddc6f8',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [Object],
      method: 'post',
      data: '{"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo","messages":[{"role":"user","content":"hey"}]}',
      url: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: true,
      _last: false,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 74,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'POST /v1/chat/completions HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: OpenAI/NodeJS/3.2.1\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Bearer MY API KEY' +
        'Content-Length: 74\r\n' +
        'Host: api.openai.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/v1/chat/completions',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'api.openai.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    data: { error: [Object] }
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

The error does say a 404 but i can't tell why and how to fix it

Comment: Can't see anything wrong. There's a few [issues](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/issues) reported around the new `createChatCompletion` but your code looks correct

Comment: Could you please try getting the actual response body logged, eg `console.error(error.response?.data ?? error.toJSON())`. Why Axios doesn't make this prominent is a complete mystery to me

Comment: oh welp i found the problem...

Comment: ```
{
  error: {
    message: 'You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.',
    type: 'insufficient_quota',
    param: null,
    code: null
  }
}
```
i didnt think to check that my bad, my credit card was being declined.

Comment: OpenAI needs to learn how to use HTTP response status numbers better... [402](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/402) or [429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) would be more appropriate